# What is the result of assigning a ULONGLONG to a 16 byte array?

Tags: c++, pointers, memset

I'm a Java developer with very little knowledge of pointers. I have the following C++ code (that someone else wrote) that I'm trying to understand:

```
ULONGLONG passedValue;
BYTE myArr[16];
memset(myArr, 0x00, sizeof myArr);
*((ULONGLONG *) myArr) = passedValue;
```

While I understand that the `memset` method call fills up the `myArr` byte array (of size 16) with 0s, I'm not sure what the last line does.

According to MSDN, [ULONGLONG is 8 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...whereas myArr is 16 bytes. What will be in `myArr` after the last statement is executed?

Comment: I didn't see definition of **iv**.

Comment: What relation does myArr have with passedValue?

Comment: Sorry guys..copy paste error. Updated the original post above..The last line should have been *((ULONGLONG *) myArr) = passedValue;

Comment: myArr should have the value of 'passedValue', but should be 16-bytes long.

Comment: Try running the code (with a specific known value for `passedValue), and printing out `myArr` afterwards. You will then know exactly `myArr` contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This term `(ULONGLONG *) myArr` will convert myArr to a pointer to ULONGLONG type.

Then, `*((ULONGLONG *) myArr)` is the value of where the pointer is pointing to.

And,

```
*((ULONGLONG *) myArr) = passedValue;
```

assigns `passedValue` to the first 8 byte of `myArr BYTE` array.

```
passedValue 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
^^^^^^^^^^^
8 bytes
```